# Error with algorithm and algorithmic packages

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic, newtxmath, garamondx

I have the following problem that involves the `algorithm` and `algorithmic` packages with the `garamondx` font. This is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[letterpapet,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{garamondx} % Font
\usepackage[garamondx, cmbraces]{newtxmath} % Mathematical font

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
        \begin{algorithmic}
            \REQUIRE $g$, $k$, $\varepsilon$
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

The error that occurs is the following: if I change `$g$` for another letter (say, `$s$`), it compiles perfectly, but (so far) the problem happens with `$g$` or with `$h$`. This problem doesn't happen if the `garamodx` and `newtxmath` packages are commented.

The error log is the following:

```
Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "asd".tex
Trying to make PK font NewG8-Ita-alt-raw at 600 DPI...
Running miktex-makemf.exe...
miktex-makemf: The NewG8-Ita-alt-raw source file could not be found. Running ttf2pk.exe...
miktex-makepk
: PK font NewG8-Ita-alt-raw could not be created.
Process exited with error(s)
```

I apologize if someone already asked this question, but I didin't find it. Thank you very much for any help you can provide.

Comment: You use MiKTeX, and  it tries tocreate bitmap fonts.Looks  like the `psfonts.map` file doesn't mention `garamondx`Just try running from the command line `updmap.exe` (in administrator and in user modes).